# spree does not give any homepage when installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to set up the basic spree home page from this guide. https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html. Here I did the following

```
$ rails new shop #I have ommited the version number 4.2.0<br> 
$ cd shop <br>
$ spree install --auto-accept
$ bundle install 
$ bundle update
```

This process works fine, some 103 gems are getting installed. But when started the server, and visited **localhost:3000**. I am getting the default welcome aboard page instead of the home page of spree as promised, more over when I visit **localhost:3000/admin** I am getting `NO route matches admin error`.

So thinking that all this has happened because of the missing version number as I have mentioned.

I did the following

```
$ rails _4.2.0_ new shop<br>
$ cd shop<br>
$ spree install --auto-accept<br> 
$ bundle install
```

I got the jquery gem versioning error, when resolved that error by specifying explicitly the version number. I am getting sprockets gem version error, What I don't understand is is there something wrong I am doing? Or is there a fix for this. Any pointers are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing `spree install --auto-accept` I was getting a message to run **bundle install .** I thought this is a post installation message, so I was doing bundle install and bundle update. Then I proceeded to start a server, and that default rails was showing up. So after running **bundle install and bundle update**, go ahead and do the `spree install --auto-accept.` Now start the server. Everything will work just fine